# package org.jetbrains.annotations does not exist

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I am facing an issue in IntelliJ when I tried to build my project through maven using

```
mvn clean install
```

I have tried different ways like changing the path of my JDK but nothing worked. Can someone help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 5):

If anyone is using a plain `Kotlin` project (without any build tool such as maven or gradle) in IntelliJ IDEA, then you can add the jetbrain's `jetbrains.annotations` library by following the steps given below:

1. Right click on the module in the `Project` panel on your left hand side, and select the `Open module settings`
2. Select `Libraries` under `Project settings`
3. Click the `+` symbol on the top of the library area and select the `From Maven...`
4. Enter `org.jetbrains:annotations`, and hit the search icon at the end of it. Then, wait for the dropdown to list the available versions of it.
5. Select the latest or appropriate version you need and also enable the `Download to:` option.
6. Then, click `OK` and you are done.

Answer (score 4):

If you really need them, add the dependency in your pom.xml :

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains/annotations -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
    <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
    <version>16.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

( https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains/annotations/16.0.1 )

Comment: Everything is added and intellij is not showing error while compiling. But I am not able to build the project. It shows error at the time of clean install command

Comment: IntelliJ knows those annotations since you're running with it ! It's quite normal. However the package is there in the dep, it should work with maven. Could you post your whole pom.xml too check if there isn't something missing ?

Answer (score 3):

For me adding `jetbrains` dependency worked fine.

Provide dependency something like this.

For Gradle:

```
implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2'
```

Answer (score 2):

just put this code in the build gradle and it will work.

**implementation 'org.jetbrains:annotations:16.0.2'**

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and arrived here looking for solutions, but I couldn't find the aforementioned pom.xml. Maybe because I'm not using Maven in my project. But I solved it by editing the *MyProject.iml* file.
I've added the following code  inside the `<component>` tags.

```
<orderEntry type="module-library">
  <library>
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$MAVEN_REPOSITORY$/org/jetbrains/annotations/20.1.0/annotations-20.1.0.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</orderEntry>
```

Now I can use the annotations in my project.